# Change case, or use callback function, in regexp_replace in PostgreSQL?

Tags: regex, postgresql, plpgsql

Is it possible to change the case of what you matched in `REGEXP_REPLACE` to upper or lower case, in Postgres 8+? In Perl you can use '\u', '\U', '\l', and '\L', but there doesn't seem to be anything similar in Postgres.

I'm trying to do something that is functionally much like `initcap`, but not quite the same.

Alternatively I think I could use a function callback, with the matches as parameters, but [it doesn't look like that is possible](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-matching.html) either.

Comment: You can user Perl, see [PL/Perl](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plperl.html).